# Count Window is Local or Global in Flink 0.9.0 Release

Tags: apache-flink

I had some problem with Flink 0.9.0 Release when I run wordcount sample modified by myself. I found that count window behaved local window which is different from the official document. And I also found a fixed bug in https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-1657. Which is right answer? Any help would be appreciated! Thank a lot

Comment: Can you share an example of your input, expected output, and actual output?

Comment: The input is four Strings and I emit each String in SourceFunction every 5s. The core code of the example is dataStream.flatMap(new WordCount.Tokenizer()).window(Count.of(8)).every(Count.of(4)).groupBy(0).sum(1).flatten().print(). The output shows that each pipeline (env.setParallelism(4)) handle each String indenpently. So I think maybe count window is local

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the canonical answer right now would be that time is global (since time is always global) and all other windows are local or not well defined.

We are aware of some problems with this and are currently reworking the API a bit for the next release. You can read the design documents here: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/FLINK/Streams+and+Operations+on+Streams and https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/FLINK/Time+and+Order+in+Streams.

With the changes we are trying to make it very clear which windows are processed in parallel and what is global/local.

Comment: Thank you, this helps me a lot

Answer (score 1):

You need to group-by before applying the window:

```
dataStream.flatMap(new WordCount.Tokenizer()).groupBy(0).window(Count.of(8)).every(Count.of(4)).sum(1).‌​flatten().print()
```

Count windows are assembled locally (as far as I know). Currently, Flink does not give any ordering guarantees, thus, building count windows locally gives the best performance.

Comment: Thanks, you are right! And I do a lot of test about window semantics and found that count window is local while time window is global. Could you give me a canonical answer